# TinyMCE integration - Plugins won't show

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce

I apologize in advance if this is not the right forum for this question, but since I am in desperate need of help I hope you may want to help me out.

I am using TastyIgniter Online Ordering System for a project. The system has a description textbox where you can add information about the product. However, it is only a plain textbox without additional functionality like *strong* tags and it won't keep the formatting.

I downloaded tinymce, put the script files in the js folder, and added these lines of code into the PHP file:

```
<script src="http://localhost/assets/js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
```

Hooray, it works partly. The textbox now has some of the functionality. It keeps the formatting and I am able to add bold, italic style to the text. Although, plugins like the image, table, hyperlink 'plugins' won't show at all. Is it possible that the textbox itself is restricted and then keeps the TinyMCE from showing these buttons or is something else wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to expand your TinyMCE init to include the plugins and toolbar/menu options you want displayed.

Take a look at this basic example of TinyMCE:

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/full-featured/

If you look at the JS tab of the example you will see there are many options available for TinyMCE in the init.

Comment: Ahh wow, great! It works now. Thank you so much for the help.